# Having two different fields symbolized to give four options in ArcGIS Online, Collector

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online, arcgis-collector, arcade

I have a integer field for "agency", and a string field for Survey Status "SURV_STATU"

Each field has two options. I used this Arcade line to see the desired symbology in ArcGIS Online.

Concatenate([$feature.agency,$feature.SURV_STATU], '')

Since I used Arcade to make that symbology change, the layer is not visible in Collector. Can anyone explain why, or show another way to symbolize the 4 outcomes of one layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Arcade expressions are not currently supported in Collector for ArcGIS.

https://community.esri.com/ideas/12988-support-arcade-expressions-in-collector